# integrate trigonometric function

Tags: integration, trigonometric-series

I have to determine the value of $\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \left(\cos (3\cdot x)\cdot \sin (x)^2\right)^2 \, dx$.

What I did was rewriting the integrand as $$\frac{1}{16}(6\cdot \sin (x)-\sin (3\cdot x)-3\cdot \sin (5\cdot x)+3\cdot \sin (7\cdot x)-\sin (9\cdot x) )$$

And then using the fourier coefficient to find $3/8\cdot\pi$.

But I believe this is no way near the right method, because it includes the expansion. How to do this simpler?

Comment: Note that the integrand is an even function regarded on a symmetric interval.

Comment: I did, but don't understand how to make use of it

Comment: Why do you think using "expansion" would not be "the right method"? Is it a correct mathematical method? Well, that's all that matters!